# VMware のゲストOSに Ubuntu を入れたが、画面が意図した通り表示されない

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

VMware にUbuntuを入れましたが画面が納得できません。
添付画像はフルスクリーンで開いたものですが、画面の左右に黒く余白があります。
アイコンが並んでいる「タスクバー」？と言うのでしょうか、このバーは例えば
Windowsを起動したときのように、バーは画面全体の左端にあるのが望ましいと思います。

[image: ubuntu]

またこの状態でubuntu softwareを開くと開いたページがこの画面内に収まってくれません。端の1/4ほどは切れた状態で画面全体を見る事は出来ません。

昨日、自宅の古いWindows10PCにOracle社の「VirtualBox」を無料で入れ、その上にubuntuを入れるとそっちはうまく言っています（と言っても動画サイトなどを見ながら設定したのですが…）。ただ動きが「もっさり」して重く感じます。

今使っている新しい方は仮想環境は「VMware Workstation 16 Pro」でその上にubuntuを入れています。サイト等を眺めながらやっていたのですが、添付画像のように画面の左右に黒い余白が開いています。
また、ubuntuOS内の言語は日本語化されていません。
Activity、Power Off, などは全て英語表記になっています。
前述した、「Virtual Box」の上に作成したubutuは日本語化されています。
無理して設定を画面いっぱいにすると以下のようにレイアウト全体が横に間延びします。

[image: ubunt]

➀「VMware Workstation 16 Pro」の上に設定したubuntuの画面のレイアウト
➁日本語化についてわかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: vmware toolsはインストールしていますか？

Comment: wmware toolsはインストール済みです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

物理的なPCでディスプレイの解像度を設定するのと同様に、仮想環境上のゲストOSでも適切な解像度を設定する必要がありますが、インストール直後の状態だと限られた選択肢からしか選ぶことができません。

まずは Ubuntu の画面で左端に並んでいるアイコンから歯車をクリックして設定画面を開き、「ディスプレイ」の項目を確認してください。

また、必要に応じて VMware Tools をインストールすることで、より大きな解像度を選択したり、ウィンドウサイズに合わせてゲストOSの画面が自動でフィットして表示させることができるようになります。

日本語表示についても、上記と同じく設定画面の中に「地域と言語」という項目があり、ここから日本語を追加して英語よりも優先させればよいでしょう。

(日本語での表示例)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございました。うまくいきました。